# Is there a way of closing programs with solpg?

Tags: solana-program

I'm used to closing programs from the command line, however I recently deployed programs with solpg and can't figure out how to close them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solana Playground supports most of the Solana CLI commands.

`solana program close <PROGRAM_ID>` to close a program.

Additionally, you can see the programs you've deployed with `solana program show --programs`.